# Split one column into multiple columns by multiple delimiters in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
                                     player     score
0   Sergio Agüero Forward — Manchester City    209.98
1            Eden Hazard Midfield — Chelsea    274.04
2          Alexis Sánchez Forward — Arsenal    223.86
3     Yaya Touré Midfield — Manchester City    197.91
4  Angel María Midfield — Manchester United    132.23
```

How could split `player` into three new columns `name`, `position` and `team`?

```
                                     player     score   name    position  team
0   Sergio Agüero Forward — Manchester City    209.98   Sergio  Forward   Manchester City
1            Eden Hazard Midfield — Chelsea    274.04   Eden    Midfield  Chelsea
2          Alexis Sánchez Forward — Arsenal    223.86   Alexis  Forward   Arsenal
3     Yaya Touré Midfield — Manchester City    197.91   Yaya    Midfield  Manchester City
4  Angel María Midfield — Manchester United    132.23   Angel   Midfield  Manchester United
```

I have considered split it two columns with `df[['name_position', 'team']] = df['player'].str.split(pat= ' — ', expand=True)`, then split `name_position` to `name` and `position`. But is there any better solutions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your solution is fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` as well if you want to do it in one go:

```
print(df["player"].str.extract(r"(?P<name>.*?)\s.*?\s(?P<position>[A-Za-z]+)\s—\s(?P<team>.*)"))

     name  position               team
0  Sergio   Forward    Manchester City
1    Eden  Midfield            Chelsea
2  Alexis   Forward            Arsenal
3    Yaya  Midfield    Manchester City
4   Angel  Midfield  Manchester United
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split a python string by space with `string.split()`. This will break up your text into `'words'`, then you can simply access the one you like, like this:

```
string =  "Sergio Agüero Forward — Manchester City"
name = string.split()[0]
position = string.split()[2]
team = string.split()[4] + (string.split().has_key(5) ? string.split()[5] : '')
```

For more complex patterns, you can use regex, which is a powerful string pattern finding tool.

Hope this helped :)